# Android studio v3.2 can't open Build Logs

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]I've just update the Android studio to 3.2 and can't find the message view

> Build APK(s): Errors while building APK. You can find the errors in the 'Messages' view.
>   [image]

Comment: You go in the Build tab and you press a button to switch to Messages view. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726216/how-to-show-android-studios-messages-window

Comment: click on /ab icon on left

Comment: post more details about your error  or upload a picture of AS when it is wrong after buiding failed.

Comment: I have no messageView  window

Answer (score 2):

The text of message is changed before some releases. It is **Build** now. also you can change view by left upper button to get details.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I have this on the android studio 3.1 but now I havn't that icon and message window

Comment: You don't have `Toggle View` icon on left upper corner?

Comment: I have add the shortcut of my view

Comment: See there is `Build` in menu. Click on that.

Comment: The first snapshot is when I clicked the build menu ... I'm not new in android ,, and not new in android studio,,, it happens when I update android studio to 3.2,,, du you have android studio 3.2?

Comment: So Build is not clickable at bottom?

Comment: I don't now ,,, I think it's new designe ,,, but when I click Build icon it open the window whick I have show

Comment: I have alredy reinstall the Android Studio ,, but nothing changed,,, I have reinstall the sdk too

Comment: I have 3.2.1 which is latest, if you can not open Build Tool, then you should file a bug in Android Issue site. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues

Comment: Thank you @Khemraj

Comment: Can you also change title of question and describe your problem well, so other developer understand it.